# WSUS report shows weeks old data and not reflecting real status

Tags: windows, wsus

Hello we have several WSUS server in our company and one of them is acting weird. Servers get patched but there is still status "Downloaded" or not even any status for the current month KBs in the WSUS console report if I open one computer details and the SQL query reports also don't show Installed states even though patching happened three weeks ago already
!
Weirdly the Last status report date is fresh from today or yesterday, but the KB statuses don't get updated.
Any idea what can be wrong and how to fix it?

Here is an example of one server, but seems like all are affected and it's hundreds of them
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you *sure* your clients do their `/reportnow` to the right server? Can you see clients sending reporets in your access log?

Comment: how else would the date be current on the server if they reported somewhere else? The patches are being approved on this WSUS and this server is in registry on the clients. Which access.log do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

is it just the WSUS or you use SCCM as well ?
Either You probably have Windows Internal Database not being updated and the performance to the DB need to be improved. if so first download : https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142258  & Run this command :
sqlcmd -S np:\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query –i "\location of your script\WSUSDBmntc.sql
You can download it from here : https://github.com/vishalnvora/WSUSDBCleaner/blob/main/WSUSDBmntc.sql

Comment: so I have found out this is already there and scheduled to run twice per month. My colleague has set this up years ago already, so that's not the problem it seems :-\